# How do I filter matched words from sentences and keep them unique?

Tags: elasticsearch

I began working on an old project and upgraded ElasticSearch from version 2.4 to 6.8 and can't figure out how to get the autocompletion to work. I'm trying to find single words in the titles of posts that match or begin with the typed phrase, but all I could achieve was getting the complete titles that contain my desired terms.

I've read several examples and tutorials that used different filters like edge_ngram and match_phrase_prefix, to no avail. Even ordered a book (Advanced Elasticsearch 7.0) but couldn't find a solution in there. Do I need to post-process my results with something like an aggregation or such?

This is how my posts are set up:

```php
$mappingProperties = [
    'title' => [
        'type'      => 'text',
        'analyzer'  => 'autocomplete_analyzer',
        'fielddata' => true,
    ],
];

$indexSettings = [
    'analysis' => [
        'filter' => [
            'autocomplete_filter' => [
                'type'     => 'edge_ngram',
                'min_gram' => 3,
                'max_gram' => 20,
            ],
        ],
        'analyzer' => [
            'autocomplete_analyzer' => [
                'tokenizer' => 'autocomplete_tokenizer',
                'filter' => [
                    'lowercase',
                    'autocomplete_filter',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'tokenizer' => [
            'autocomplete_tokenizer' => [
                'type' => 'edge_ngram',
                'min_gram'    => 2,
                'max_gram'    => 20,
                'token_chars' => ['letter'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

And this is how my search query looks like:

```php
$params = [
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'match' => [
                'status' => 1,
            ],
            'match' => [
                'title' => $term,
            ],
        ],
        'aggs' => [
            'autocomplete' => [
                'terms' => [
                    'field'   => 'title',
                    'order'   => ['_count' => 'desc'],
                    'include' => $term . '.*',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

When I run a search for the partial term 'Zahnar' (German here) I get the following results:

```php
[0] => [
    [key] => zahnarz
    [doc_count] => 82
]

[1] => [
    [key] => zahnarzt
    [doc_count] => 82
]

[2] => [
    [key] => zahnarztp
    [doc_count] => 82
]

[3] => [
    [key] => zahnarztpr
    [doc_count] => 29
]

[4] => [
    [key] => zahnarztpra
    [doc_count] => 27
]

[5] => [
    [key] => zahnarztprax
    [doc_count] => 27
]

[6] => [
    [key] => zahnarztpraxi
    [doc_count] => 27
]

[7] => [
    [key] => zahnarztpraxis
    [doc_count] => 15
]

[8] => [
    [key] => zahnarztpraxe
    [doc_count] => 15
]

[9] => [
    [key] => zahnarztpraxen
    [doc_count] => 12
]
```

It seems that those are all the possible tokenized word parts hat have been analyzed during indexing. I would only want full words, i.e.: results 1, 7 and 9.

Comment: In you mapping you are not using your custom analyzer. You need to replace 'analyzer' => 'standard' with autocomplete_analyzer

Comment: Oh, my bad. I struggled putting together a working version as I've been editing the arrays for two weeks now. I've updated the code in the question.

Comment: 'title' => $term . '.*',  , you dont need to give (.*)  and include' => [ 'pattern' => $term  '.*', ] try by removing pattern. I don't understand the purpose of aggregation , are titles duplicate?

Comment: Thans. Yes, there can be duplicate titles. It works when leaving out _'pattern'_, but removing the _'.*'_ gives only results that exactly match the search term instead of words starting with the term.
I updated the code again, with example results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create mapping like below

```
PUT index38
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",     ----> for searching
        "analyzer": "autocomplete_analyzer",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"   --- > for terms aggregation
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "autocomplete_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 20
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "autocomplete_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "autocomplete_filter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "autocomplete_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 20,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Multiple tokens in aggregation are coming due to setting [fielddata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html#before-enabling-fielddata) as true

From docs

> A text field is analyzed before indexing so that a value like New York
>   can be found by searching for new or for york. A terms aggregation on
>   this field will return a new bucket and a york bucket, when you
>   probably want a single bucket called New York. Instead, you should
>   have a text field for full text searches, and an unanalyzed keyword
>   field with doc_values enabled for aggregations

You need to create a subfield called keyword with type [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html), which stores entire text as a single token.

Edit1:
Mapping

```
GET index38/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": {
              "query": "Zahnar",
              "analyzer": "autocomplete_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "autocomplete": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "title.keyword",
        "include": "zahnar.*", 
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Data:

```
 [
      {
        "_index" : "index38",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ilUK_G0Bl2iO22h0waYm",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "Zahnarzt"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index38",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "i1UK_G0Bl2iO22h0xabf",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "zahnarztpraxis"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index38",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "jFUK_G0Bl2iO22h0zabu",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "zahnarztpraxen"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index38",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "jVUK_G0Bl2iO22h00qYI",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "Zahnarzt abc"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Query:

```
GET index38/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": {
              "query": "Zahnar",
              "analyzer": "autocomplete_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "autocomplete": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "title.keyword",
        "include": "zahnar.*", 
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
[
      {
        "_index" : "index38",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "i1UK_G0Bl2iO22h0xabf",
        "_score" : 0.90610546,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "zahnarztpraxis"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index38",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "jFUK_G0Bl2iO22h0zabu",
        "_score" : 0.90610546,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "zahnarztpraxen"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index38",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ilUK_G0Bl2iO22h0waYm",
        "_score" : 0.8928052,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "Zahnarzt"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index38",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "jVUK_G0Bl2iO22h00qYI",
        "_score" : 0.8913534,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "Zahnarzt abc"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "autocomplete" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "zahnarzt",
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : "zahnarztpraxen",
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : "zahnarztpraxis",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

There is another option if you don;t use autocomplete_analyzer

```
GET index38/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "title": {
              "query": "zahn"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
 "highlight" : {
        "fields" : {
            "title" : {}
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to get tokens from highlight fields in client side.
and match phrase will match text anywhere and is not suitable for autocomplete type of functionalities

Comment: I didn't know about subfields, thanks! I added that and changed the _field_ in the search parameters to _keyword_, but the _buckets_ in the result are empty now. _Hits_ from regular search look good, though.

Comment: You aggregation will be like below "aggs": {
    "autocomplete": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "title.keyword",
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }, check for title.keyword

Comment: did above work? Can you paste your aggregation query

Comment: Unfortunately not, I only managed to get a whole title as a result once and only with a very specific search term. This is the query I use:
'aggs' => [
    'autocomplete' => [
        'terms' => [
            'field' => 'title.keyword',
            'order' => ['_count' => 'desc'],
            'include' => $term
        ],
    ],
],

Comment: Either remove include(you don't require it) or pass $term in lowercase  ex  "include": "zahnar.*",

Comment: "include" and exclude are regex so they have to be an exact match as indexed documents

Comment: Thanks so far, but not quite.
After removing _include_ the keys in the resulting bucket are properly grouped and ordered, but I still get the whole titles and not the single keyword from within them.

Comment: I have added one edit can you check if it works for you